# Button Click Event fires Twice

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

so I'm having a bit of trouble using Axios with VueJS (I'm using the [Quasar Framework](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar)). I'm making a very simple e-commerce website. I have a button on the product page that allows the user to insert that product to the cart.

```
<q-btn
     @click="addToCart()"
>
    Add to Cart
</q-btn>
```

When the user clicks the button I execute the `addToCart()` method:

```
methods: {
  addToCart () {
      axios.post(this.getRootURL + 'app/actions/add_to_cart.php', {
        product_id: this.$route.params.product_id,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        user_id: LocalStorage.get.item('user_id')
      }).then(response => {
        console.log("Product added...")
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Error... ")
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm facing a problem. It's as if the data gets inserted twice. The first row gets a null `user_id` and the second row get the correct `user_id` ([See image](https://ibb.co/kRzCiw)).

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with VueJS or Axios because when using Postman and sending a request directly to the file, the data only gets inserted once correctly.

Can anyone help? Has this happened to anyone else before? :/

**UPDATE**
This is my server side PHP script.

add_to_cart.php

```
<?php
  require '../Functions.php';
  $obj = new User_Functions();

  $addToCart = $obj->addToCart($_POST['product_id'], $_POST['quantity'], $_POST['user_id']);

  if($addToCart){
    echo 'true';
  }else{
    echo 'false';
  }

?>
```

Functions.php

This is the method being executed inside the `User_Functions` class (I'm using [Medoo.in](https://medoo.in/) to manage my queries to my database):

```
require 'init.php'; //Connection to my database

class User_Functions {
 public function addToCart($product_id, $quantity, $user_id){
      global $database;

      $check_if_cart_active = $database->count("cart", [
        "user_id" => $user_id
      ]);

      //CHECK IF USER HAS AN ACTIVE CART
      if($check_if_cart_active == 0){
        // If user doesn't have an active cart add new cart and add the cart item
        $database->insert("cart", [
          "user_id" => $user_id,
          "created_at" => time()
        ]);
        $cart_id = $database->id();

        $database->insert("cart_products", [
          "cart_id" => $cart_id,
          "product_id" => $product_id,
          "quantity" => $quantity,
          "created_at" => time()
        ]);
      }else{
        // Get cart_id of the active cart
        $cart_id = $database->select("cart", [
          "cart_id"
        ], [
          "user_id" => $user_id
        ]);
        $cart_id = $cart_id[0]['cart_id'];

        //CHECK IF PRODUCT IS ALREADY IN CART
        $check_if_product_in_cart = $database->count("cart_products",[
          "AND" => [
            "cart_id"    => $cart_id,
            "product_id" => $product_id
          ]
        ]);

        //IF PRODUCT ISN'T IN CART ADD IT ELSE UPDATE THE QUANTITY
        if($check_if_product_in_cart == 0){
          $database->insert("cart_products", [
            "cart_id" => $cart_id,
            "product_id" => $product_id,
            "quantity" => $quantity,
            "created_at" => time()
          ]);
        }else{
          $database->update("cart_products", [
            "quantity" => $quantity
          ], [
            "AND" => [
              "cart_id" => $cart_id,
              "product_id" => $product_id
            ]
          ]);
        }
      }

      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi have you tried initializing LocalStorage.get.item('user_id') outside the post? Im guessing its because you're executing a serverside script while getting a paramter from local storage which is client side, could you try to pass first the user id in a var and use that var instead? like "var userId = LocalStorage.get.item('user_id');" then in your objects "user_Id: userId".

Comment: I just tried it and still getting that null value in the database. I'll update the post and include the server side PHP script.

Comment: HI @Brian Moreno I'm sorry for stepping into your question, and to admit that unfortunately Im not really knowledgeable in vue.js yet, but for me i guess you could have put a validation(in your php script) instead to check if a user_id is null else then you can exec your Insert query thereafter. As of now this could be my best advice for you but not saying that I had the answer. Some may still give an answer to this yet much better to that of my advice.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the advice. Checking if my `profile_id` is null server side actually worked. However, I'll still try to get an answer using VueJS because it could be an issue somewhere in the future.  :)

Comment: Alright then. Goodluck @Brian Moreno!

Comment: Did you try to call the addToCart function without brackets? Like `<q-btn @click="addToCart"></q-btn`